# Where can I find a control or method for making expanding table like Facebook activity feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, controls

I would like to build a table that expands when you scroll, similar to the Facebook activity feed behavior. What is the best way to accomplish this assuming I have jQuery, etc available to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the behaviour that auto retrieving further contents when the viewport get to the bottom.

Have you tried [Infinite Scroller](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/infinitescroller.html) ?

If it doesn't fit your need, you can always start from their code and develop your own.